# problems with jquery Tree Traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery

(1) I've a scenario where there are some checkbox with a "Other" (user typed option) checkbox

[image]

(2) When clicking on the checkbox of "Other", a input field will come and cover the "Other" text.

[image]

(3) User can type at there and there is an "ok" button beside the checkbox.

[image]

(4) When user click the "Ok" button, input field will be gone and user typed text will come at the place of previous "Other" text. At the same time new "Other" fields should come after previous. Also previous "Other" shouldn't expand any more as it's not "Other" anymore(for example, it's now Black).

[image]

To make this, I've written jQuery like this:

```
$('.otherOption input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.otherOption').find('.box').toggle();    
});

$('.ok').click(function() {
    var value = $('.optionInput').val();

    $('.box').hide();
    $('.otherOption p').text(value);
    $('.otherOption').removeClass('otherOption');
    $(this).closest('.otherOption').append('<div class="block otherOption"><input type="checkbox" /> <p>Other</p><div class="box"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Provide your option" class="optionInput" /><button class="ok">Ok</button></div></div>');
});
```

I think, I can write some script correctly. But, as I ain't good at jQuery, I can't write the jquery selector(.closest(),.parents(),.next() etc) that's why, my script is not working. So, please help me to make my script correct. Thanks in advance

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/a695jk2d/)

Comment: What's it doing that you don't want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start. A couple things to make this work the way you want.

1. You code `$('.otherOption').removeClass('otherOption');` removes all instances of the otherOption class which is why your append isn't working.
2. If you removed the line mentioned above, you're appending the new checkbox inside the wrapper of the other checkbox which I can imagine isn't the desired result. I would imagine you want the new checkbox to come `.after()` the old otherOption box.

These being said remove this line:
    `$('.otherOption').removeClass('otherOption');`

and change your `$(this).closest('.otherOption')...` to

```
$(this)
    .closest('.otherOption')
    .removeClass('otherOption')
    .after('<div class="block otherOption"><input type="checkbox" /> <p>Other</p><div class="box"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Provide your option" class="optionInput" /><button class="ok">Ok</button></div></div>');
```

A side note - cause you'll wonder later - your `.click()` function's won't work more than once. `.click()` binds to all matching objects on the page load. So any items added dynamically after page load will not work. Look into using jQuery's `.on()` method. This will ensure you're code works on all matching items no matter when they're added to the DOM.

Edit: One other thing, I noticed that when you repetitively added items, it always added the text from the first box b/c you are not removing the used text boxes. I've added `$(this).closest('.box').remove();` to the end of the JS code to fix this issue.

Here's a working fiddle with jQuery's `.on()` implemented http://jsfiddle.net/a695jk2d/4/

Don't just copy and paste it, understand it.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks. I'm trying to understand everything

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to simply insert a new structure above your already existing "Other" option. Why replace it's text, and add a whole new 'other' option block? This version will insert a new option above the "Other" option. This way you also only need to bind to the element once as well.

```
$( '.ok' ).click(function () {
  var value = $( '.optionInput' ).val();
  $( '.optionInput' ).val('');

  $( this ).parent().parent().find( '.box, p' ).toggle();
  $( '.otherOption input[type="checkbox"]' ).attr( 'checked', false );
  $( '#optionContainer' ).append(
    '<div class="block"><input type="checkbox" /> <p>' + value + '</p></div>'
  );
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/a695jk2d/7/)